# How and where do you report "bad" servers?

Tags: nginx, hacking, reporting

I recently setup an nginx that was open to the world in order to serve an API to global users.

It's getting a lot of "prodding" (ie: weakness testing/hacking attempts) from an IP address registered to Hostway.ru hosting providers.

I used this tool to find out more: https://bgp.he.net. I've contacted hostway and asked them to investigate and bring this activity to a halt - no response, no surprise.

Is there an authority of some kind, or a global blacklist, that I could report this activity to in order to hold the company to account?

I've configured my nginx to deny all requests from that IP now. Is there anything else I should be doing? My worry is that they can just change IP/host and start again. How do I protect myself from this sort of traffic in the long run?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the internet. It will be a waste of your time to report IPs that are trying to get into your nginx server. Security companies host a bunch of honeypots to create their own blacklists that they then feed to their security products and/or publish the list.

Comment: You could use firewall rules and/or an IPS to drop specific traffic that is bothering your webserver, the rules for both being like your own blacklist. Active server administration will help you identify the nature of the probing/hacking attacks and help you craft firewall/IPS rules to help mitigate the threats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for an abuse contact direct to them (not any technical or sales contacts). Send a very specific report detailing what traffic and citing their own terms of use. Not finding an abuse specific contact on their web site is a bad sign, do not expect much action from them.

On the Internet, there is a lot of nasty traffic, you will not have time to report it all.

Implement local deny lists such as with fail2ban. Consider using  one of the many block lists or host reputation APIs, some of which can be integrated into your security controls.

Apply security updates quickly as always. Do not delay updating anything you have public facing, including web servers, web apps, and any libraries they use.

Comment: I stopped reporting things long ago, aside from occasionally the most egregious stuff.